# mysql validate json on longtext column

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-json

I have an existing longtext column in a huge table (100MM rows) which includes json strings. Changing the type to json would lock the table. As an alternative I thought I could add json validation to the longtext column on create and update.

I do not have much experience with triggers. how would that work? I know it should be something like this:

```
TRIGGER `before_insert_user`
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
END;

TRIGGER `before_update_user`
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
END;
```

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return on your instance?

Comment: @BillKarwin 8.0.15

Comment: *which includes json strings* - ?? Looks like the value is a text but some part of it is JSON...

Answer (score 0):

Demo:

```
mysql> create table users (id serial primary key, properties longtext);

mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create trigger before_insert_user before insert on users for each row
    -> begin
    -> if not json_type(NEW.properties) = 'OBJECT' then
    -> signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'properties must be a valid JSON object';
    -> end if;
    -> end//

mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> insert into users set properties = 'yadda yadda';
ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_type: "Invalid value." at position 0.

mysql> insert into users set properties = '["yadda yadda"]';
ERROR 1644 (45000): properties must be a valid JSON object

mysql> insert into users set properties = '{"yadda": "yadda"}';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

However, I would change the data type to JSON. I would use [pt-online-schema-change](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html) to make the alteration without locking the table.

That example at least ensures the longtext column is valid JSON format, and also is a JSON object (not an array or a scalar).

If you need the JSON to comply with a more precise format, read about [JSON_SCHEMA_VALID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-validation-functions.html).